# what is meaning of [iter(list)]*2 in python?

Tags: python, iterator, zip

I have found below code in web, result is tuple of two elements in list, how to understand `[iter(list)]*2`?

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b=zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)
list(b)

[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

------------
[iter(lst)]*2
[<list_iterator at 0x1aff33917f0>, <list_iterator at 0x1aff33917f0>]
```

I check `[iter(lst)]*2`, same iterator above, so meaning `iter` repeat double,
so, if i check num from 2 to 3, result should be `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6),(7,8,NaN)]`
but delete 7,8

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b=zip(*[iter(lst)]*3)
list(b)
--------------
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what specific part is confusing you? Have you checked the output of each step? As in check the output of `[iter(lst)]`, then check the output of `[iter(lst)]*2` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a tricky construct to explain. I'll give it a shot:

with `[iter(lst)]` you create a list with with one item. The item is an iterator over a list.

whenever python tries to get an element from this iterator, then the next element of `lst` is returned until no more element is available.

Just try following:

```
i = iter(lst)
next(i)
next(i)
```

the output should look like:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  
>>> i = iter(lst)
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
3
>>> next(i)
4
>>> next(i)
5
>>> next(i)
6
>>> next(i)
7
>>> next(i)
8
>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Now you create a list that contains twice **exactly the same** iterator.
You do this with
`itlst = [iter(lst)] * 2`

try out following:

```
itlst1 = [iter(lst)] * 2
itlst2 = [iter(lst), iter(lst)]
print(itlst1)
print(itlst2)
```

The result will look something like:

```
>>> itlst1 = [iter(lst)] * 2
>>> itlst2 = [iter(lst), iter(lst)]
>>> print(itlst1)
[<list_iterator object at 0x7f9251172b00>, <list_iterator object at 0x7f9251172b00>]
>>> print(itlst2)
[<list_iterator object at 0x7f9251172b70>, <list_iterator object at 0x7f9251172ba8>]
```

What is important to notice is, that `itlst1` is a list containing twice the same iterator, whereas `itlst2` contains two different iterators.

to illustrate try to type:

```
next(itlst1[0])
next(itlst1[1])
next(itlst1[0])
next(itlst1[1])
```

and compare it with:

```
next(itlst2[0])
next(itlst2[1])
next(itlst2[0])
next(itlst2[1])
```

The result is:

```
>>> next(itlst1[0])
1
>>> next(itlst1[1])
2
>>> next(itlst1[0])
3
>>> next(itlst1[1])
4
>>> 
>>> next(itlst2[0])
1
>>> next(itlst2[1])
1
>>> next(itlst2[0])
2
>>> next(itlst2[1])
2
```

Now to the `zip()` function ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip ):

Try following:

```
i = iter(lst)
list(zip(i, i))
```

`zip()` with two parameters.
Whenver you try to get the next element from `zip` it will do following:

- get one value from the iterable that is the first parameter
- get one value from the iterable that is the second parameter
- return a tuple with these two values.

`list(zip(xxx))` will do this repeatedly and store the result in a list.

The result will be:

```
>>> i = iter(lst)
>>> list(zip(i, i))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

The next trick being used is the `*` that is used to use the first element as first parameter to a function call, the second element as second parameter and so forth) [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

so writing:

```
itlst1 = [iter(lst)] * 2
list(zip(*itlst1))
```

is in this case identical to

```
i = iter(lst)
itlst1 = [i] * 2
list(zip(itlst1[0], itlst1[1]))
```

which is identical to

```
list(zip(i, i))
```

which I explained already.

Hope this explains most of the above tricks.

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Comment: Really nice work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`iter(lst)` turns a list into an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). Iterators let you step lazily through an iterable by calling [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) until the iterator runs out of items.

`[iter(lst)]` puts the iterator into a single-element list.

`[iter(lst)] * 2` makes 2 copies of the iterator in the list, giving

```
it = iter(lst)
[it, it]
```

Both list elements are aliases of the same underlying iterator object, so whenever `next()` is called on either of the iterators as `zip` exhausts them, successive elements are yielded.

`*[...]` unpacks the list of the two copies of the same iterator into the arguments for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). This creates a zip object that lets you iterate through tuples of elements from each of its arguments.

`list(...)` iterates through the zip object and copies the elements into a list. Since both zipped iterators point to the same underlying iterator, we get the sequential elements seen in your output.

Without using the iterator alias, you'd get

```
>>> list(zip(iter(lst), iter(lst)))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8)]
```

A similar way to write `list(zip(*[iter(lst)] * 2))` is `list(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))`, which seems a bit less magical (if much less performant).

The explanation for

```
>>> list(zip(*[iter(lst)] * 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

omitting elements is that the first time the zip object tries to yield a `None` result on any of the argument iterables, it stops and does not generate a tuple. You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to match your expected behavior, more or less:

```
>>> list(zip_longest(*[iter(lst)] * 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, None)]
```

See the canonical answer [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) if the `[...] * 2` aliasing behavior is surprising.