# Python slow execution

Tags: python, list

I made a script which inserts two lists into another every each 4 element but it takes a really long time to complete.
Here are my two very long lists:

```
listOfX = ['567','765','456','457','546'....] len(383656)
listOfY = ['564','345','253','234','123'....] len(383656)
```

And the other list which contain some data and where I want to add the data of the other lists:

```
cleanData = ['2020-04-28T01:44:59.392043', 'c57', '0', '2020-04-28T01:44:59.392043', 'c57', '1'....] len(1145146)
```

Here what I want:

```
cleanData = ['2020-04-28T01:44:59.392043', 'c57', '0', 567, 564, '2020-04-28T01:44:59.392043', 'c57', '1', 765, 345]
```

Finally, here my code:

```py
  ## ADDING X AND Y TO ORIGINAL LIST
  addingValue = True
  valueItem = ""
  loopValue = 3
  xIndex = 0
  yIndex = 0
  print(len(listOfX))

  while addingValue:

    if xIndex > len(listOfX):
      break

    try:
      cleanData.insert(loopValue, listOfY[yIndex])
      cleanData.insert(loopValue, listOfX[xIndex])

    except IndexError:
      addingValue = False
      break

    xIndex += 1
    yIndex += 1
    loopValue += 5
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: How are you trying to merge the lists? Do you have code?

Comment: Can you add the code you wrote to the question please.

Comment: yes sure, wait im adding it

Comment: you don't show your code. so difficult to improve performance.

Comment: You are going to have to show some code if you want help optimizing it.  I would guess that the main issue is that you are loading huge lists into memory.  This is going to be excruciatingly slow.  You should instead try to use a iterator to load elements on demand, and consume output as you combine it instead of storing it all in memory, if possible.

Comment: I THink the main issue is, that you are inserting elements instead od constructing a new list.

Do you rally have to insert or could you just create a new list?

Comment: @gelonida Yes i could create a new one i will try

Comment: I see a problem here: `listOfX` and `listOfY` have 383656 items each, and `cleanData` has only 1145146, which is less than 3*383656; so, if you want to add one item from each of the first two lists after every group of 3 items in `cleanData`, you'll have unused elements left in `listOfX`, `listOfY`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: As mentioned above, insertion into an existing list is very expensive.  It would be better to for i in range(len(<smallestlist>)): then append elements to a new list, or as I mentioned in my previous comment, even better consume and use it group of elements as you combine them instead of putting them back in a list.  You could do that via a generator like so is demonstrated here: https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your solution was, that in your solution you inserted elements 2 * 383656 times into an existing list. 
Every time all the elements after the insertion point had to be shifted.

Thus it's faster to create a new list.

If for any reason you want that `cleanData` stays the same old object with the new data (perhaps, because another function / object has a reference to it and should see the changed data) then write

```
cleanData[:] = blablabla
```

instead of

```
cleanData = blablabla
```

I wrote following two solutions (second faster one only after answer got accepted)

```
import functools
import operator
cleanData = functools.reduce(
    operator.iconcat,
    (list(v) for v in zip(*([iter(cleanData)] * 3), listOfX, listOfY)),
    [])
```

and

```
import itertools
cleanData = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    (v for v in zip(*([iter(cleanData)] * 3), listOfX, listOfY)),
    ))
```

In order to understand the `zip(*([iter(cleanData)] * 3), listOfX, listOfY)` construct you might look at [what is meaning of [iter(list)]*2 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670945/what-is-meaning-of-iterlist2-in-python/61671190#61671190)

Potential downside of my first solution (depending on the context). Using `functools.reduce` and `operator.iconcat` creates a list and no generator.

The second solution returns a list. If you want a generator, then just remove `list(` and one trailing `)` and it will be a generator

Second solution is (about 2x) faster than the first one.

Then I wrote some code to compare performance and results of the two given solutions and mine:

Not a very big difference (2.5x), but the second solution seems to be a bit faster than @Błotosmętek's first solution and  Alain T.'s solution.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import functools
import itertools
import operator
import time

@contextmanager
def measuretime(comment):
    print("=" * 76)
    t0 = time.time()
    yield comment
    print("%s: %5.3fs" % (comment, time.time() - t0))
    print("-" * 76 + "\n")


N = 383656
t0 = time.time()
with measuretime("create listOfX"):
    listOfX = list(range(N))

with measuretime("create listOfY"):
    listOfY = list(range(1000000, 1000000 + N))

print("listOfX", len(listOfX), listOfX[:10])
print("listOfY", len(listOfY), listOfY[:10])

with measuretime("create cleanData"):
    origCleanData = functools.reduce(
        operator.iconcat,
        (["2020-010-1T01:00:00.%06d" % i, "c%d" % i, "%d" %i] for i in range(N)),
        [])

print("cleanData", len(origCleanData), origCleanData[:12])

cleanData = list(origCleanData)
with measuretime("funct.reduce operator icat + zip"):
    newcd1 = functools.reduce(
        operator.iconcat,
        (list(v) for v in zip(*([iter(cleanData)] * 3), listOfX, listOfY)),
        [])

print("NEW", len(newcd1), newcd1[:3*10])

cleanData = list(origCleanData)
with measuretime("itertools.chain + zip"):
    cleanData = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (v for v in zip(*([iter(cleanData)] * 3), listOfX, listOfY)),
        ))

print("NEW", len(cleanData), cleanData[:3*10])
assert newcd1 == cleanData

cleanData = list(origCleanData)
with measuretime("blotosmetek"):
    tmp = []
    n = min(len(listOfX), len(listOfY), len(cleanData)//3)
    for i in range(n):
       tmp.extend(cleanData[3*i : 3*i+3])
       tmp.append(listOfX[i])
       tmp.append(listOfY[i])
    cleanData = tmp

print("NEW", len(cleanData), cleanData[:3*10])
assert newcd1 == cleanData


cleanData = list(origCleanData)
with measuretime("alainT"):
    cleanData = [ v for i,x,y in zip(range(0,len(cleanData),3),listOfX,listOfY)
                for v in (*cleanData[i:i+3],x,y) ]

print("NEW", len(cleanData), cleanData[:3*10])
assert newcd1 == cleanData
```

Output on my old PC looks like:

```
============================================================================
create listOfX: 0.013s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================================================================
create listOfY: 0.013s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

listOfX 383656 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
listOfY 383656 [1000000, 1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 1000004, 1000005, 1000006, 1000007, 1000008, 1000009]
============================================================================
create cleanData: 0.454s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

cleanData 1150968 ['2020-010-1T01:00:00.000000', 'c0', '0', '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000001', 'c1', '1', '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000002', 'c2', '2', '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000003', 'c3', '3']
============================================================================
funct.reduce operator icat + zip: 0.240s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NEW 1918280 ['2020-010-1T01:00:00.000000', 'c0', '0', 0, 1000000, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000001', 'c1', '1', 1, 1000001, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000002', 'c2', '2', 2, 1000002, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000003', 'c3', '3', 3, 1000003, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000004', 'c4', '4', 4, 1000004, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000005', 'c5', '5', 5, 1000005]
============================================================================
itertools.chain + zip: 0.109s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NEW 1918280 ['2020-010-1T01:00:00.000000', 'c0', '0', 0, 1000000, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000001', 'c1', '1', 1, 1000001, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000002', 'c2', '2', 2, 1000002, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000003', 'c3', '3', 3, 1000003, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000004', 'c4', '4', 4, 1000004, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000005', 'c5', '5', 5, 1000005]
============================================================================
blotosmetek: 0.370s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NEW 1918280 ['2020-010-1T01:00:00.000000', 'c0', '0', 0, 1000000, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000001', 'c1', '1', 1, 1000001, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000002', 'c2', '2', 2, 1000002, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000003', 'c3', '3', 3, 1000003, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000004', 'c4', '4', 4, 1000004, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000005', 'c5', '5', 5, 1000005]
============================================================================
alainT: 0.258s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NEW 1918280 ['2020-010-1T01:00:00.000000', 'c0', '0', 0, 1000000, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000001', 'c1', '1', 1, 1000001, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000002', 'c2', '2', 2, 1000002, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000003', 'c3', '3', 3, 1000003, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000004', 'c4', '4', 4, 1000004, '2020-010-1T01:00:00.000005', 'c5', '5', 5, 1000005]
```

Comment: Just In case I added a few more comments to my answer

Comment: found an even faster solution. with `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` and `zip()`

will adapt my answer

Comment: I also corrected the comparison code. I forgot to reset cleanData before each test, so 3rd and 4th test didn't have correct input values

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation of shelister's suggestion:

```
tmp = []
n = min(len(listOfX), len(listOfY), len(cleanData)//3)
for i in range(n):
   tmp.extend(cleanData[3*i : 3*i+3])
   tmp.append(listOfX[i])
   tmp.append(listOfY[i])
cleanData = tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be much faster:

```
cleanData = [ v for i,x,y in zip(range(0,len(cleanData),3),listOfX,listOfY) 
                for v in (*cleanData[i:i+3],x,y) ]
```

*If you use parentheses instead of brackets, the expression becomes a generator that you can use to iterate through the merged data (e.g. with a for loop) without actually creating a copy in a new list*

Answer (score 0):

Building on Blotometek's with a generator, you would do something like this:

```
def get_next_group():
    n = min(len(listOfX), len(listOfY), len(cleanData)//3)
    for i in range(n):
        tmp = cleanData[3*i : 3*i+3]
        tmp.append(listOfX[i])
        tmp.append(listOfY[i])

        yield tmp

#in you main code:

for x in get_next_group():
    #do something with x
    pass
```

The advantage of the above code is that combination is only done piece by piece as you request it.  If you do something with it, and don't store it in a list in memory, memory overhead is reduced.  Since you are no longer memory-bound, the CPU can immediately be processing other instructions on each chunk instead of waiting for everything to be combined first.