# Python zip function with iterator vs iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble understanding working of the `zip()` function in python when an *iterator* is passed in instead of *iterable*.

Have a look at these two print statements:

```
string = "ABCDEFGHI"

print(list(zip(*[iter(string)] * 3)))
# Output: [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I')]

print(list(zip(*[string] * 3)))
# Output: [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C'), ('D', 'D', 'D'), ('E', 'E', 'E'), ('F', 'F', 'F'), ('G', 'G', 'G'), ('H', 'H', 'H'), ('I', 'I', 'I')]
```

Can someone explain me the working of *zip()* in both the cases?

Comment: The problem is, although you use `* 3` and want to get `[iter(string), iter(string), iter(string)]`, actually these three `iter(string)` point to the same object. Which means iter one will also affect two others. Um... a little bit confusing, hope you understand what I mean. While `[string] * 3` will result in true three different string.

Comment: That's why we cannot create nested list just by `[[]] * 3` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that for `[iter(string)] * 3`, `zip` creates aliases of a single iterator. For `[string] * 3`, `zip` creates unique iterators per argument. The shorter output without duplicates is `zip` exhausting the single aliased iterator.

See [what is meaning of [iter(list)]*2 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670945/what-is-meaning-of-iterlist2-in-python/61671053#61671053) for more details on how `[iter(...)] * 2` works and causes potentially unexpected results.

See the canonical answer [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) if the `[...] * 3` aliasing behavior is surprising.

Comment: The string is not copied; as you said initially, it's aliased. The difference is that in order to iterate, Python will create a separate iterator for each of the `zip` arguments when they're strings, but reuse the passed-in iterator when it's passed an iterator.

Comment: Updated to be a bit clearer about what's going on. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the additional content.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a clearer example:

```
a = iter("123456")  # One iterator 
list(zip(a, a, a)) 
# [('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6')]
```

vs

```
a = iter("123456")
b = iter("123456")
c = iter("123456")
list(zip(a, b, c))
# [('1', '1', '1'), ('2', '2', '2'), ('3', '3', '3'), ('4', '4', '4'), ('5', '5', '5'), ('6', '6', '6')]
```

Obviously in the first example `a` can only yield 6 elements, and has to yield 3 to `zip` whenever `zip` needs to create a value.  In contrast, the second example has 18 elements total, and yields them in 6 groups of 3.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this properly, first make sure you understand the relevant fundamentals: the Python [iterator protocol](https://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/) and [object identity versus equality](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/02/28/python-101-equality-vs-identity/).

```
print(list(zip(*[string] * 3)))
```

We compute the list `[string] * 3`, and pass each element from that list to `zip`, so it's the same as if we had written `zip(string, string, string)`. Python implicitly creates a separate iterator for each of the arguments (even though it's the same string object in each case - not copies!), and each one iterates over the same string. The first time through, each iterator finds the `'A'`, and so on.

```
print(list(zip(*[iter(string)] * 3)))
```

Now we have made a single iterator for the string, and passed it to `zip` in three argument positions. Python's iteration logic attempts to "create an iterator" for that iterator in each case; but *the iterator of an iterator is itself* (not a copy of itself!). So once the iteration begins, `zip` will be using the same iterator object three times to create each of its outputs. And each time it grabs the `next` element from the iterator, it will be affected by the previous attempts. So the first time through, `zip` requests three elements from that same iterator, and gets `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the additional content.